# Is it possible to add packages to an openfaas container?

Tags: python-3.x, containers, openfaas

I am new to Openfaas. I have Python code that has dependency on Xvfb. I have executed this code just fine running under Ubuntu, however this code fails when trying to run in an Openfaas container. I get the following error.

> exit status 1
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/app/python/easyprocess/**init**.py", line 168, in start
> self.popen = subprocess.Popen(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1819, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb'

from what I can tell, the Xvfb package is not installed. In Ubuntu I resolved this by doing

> sudo apt-get install xvfb

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of this in Openfaas. From my research, I should be able to add "build_options" to the .yml file. I tried the following, but the package still does not install.

[image: yml configuration]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Cna you check the generated `Dockerfile` and post the content? What if you build it using something like `faas-cli build --lang python3 --build-arg ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE=xvfb`

Comment: @Hackerman. That is exactly what I ended up needing in that situation. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help @Dave 